# IOS How to call a method in a ViewController if modal is dismissed

Tags: ios, objective-c, modalviewcontroller

In all view controllers I  `present` a `ModalViewController` after I  dismiss modal view controller I want to call a method in current view controller.

I have to presentModalViewController I cant push it because it is a form sheet. Since I cant push it `(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated` is not called when I dismiss the form sheet.

Btw form sheet is a settings menu and I have to call it in every view controller, so I cant use notifications  because there are over 20 View controllers and only one settings menu;

```
Navigation controller -> Root- > VC1 - > VC2 - > VC3 ->VC4........... VC20......
                                  |       |       |     |               |
                                 Menu    Menu    Menu  Menu           Menu
```

I present menu:

```
UIStoryboard*  sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard"
                                              bundle:nil];
SettingsListViewController *settingsVC = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SettingsListViewController"];
UINavigationController *modalViewNavController= [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:settingsVC];
modalViewNavController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
modalViewNavController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
[self presentModalViewController:modalViewNavController animated:YES];
```

I dismiss it :

```
 //dissmiss view
 [self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES] ;
```

In View Controllers I want to Call;
`[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];`

Is there a way to call a method in View Controller when form sheet is dismissed ?

Comment: Can you able to use NSNotificationCenter?

Comment: @Nirav there are over 20 VCs and only one form sheet controller how can I call notification center? First I need to now which VC presented forms sheet then send a specific notification for that VC, It is not quiet easy

Answer (score 1):

Since iOS 5, you can use the `presentingViewController` property of every `UIViewController` to see 1) if they're being presented modally in the first place and 2) who it is that's presenting them modally then. So if you present your form sheet by calling `[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:modalViewNavController animated:YES]`, the presenting view controller will then be the root navigation controller and you can tell it to pop to root at the same time you dismiss the modal presentation.

By the way, there's also a `storyboard` property in every view controller which has originated from a storyboard, so you could use that one directly when instantiating new storyboard view controllers by name.

Answer (score 1):

Make your own delegate and set the view controller that presents the view as delegate.. and call from modalVC when it is about to be dismissed.

Answer (score -1):

You can set `modalViewController.parentViewController = self;` and then work with it from modal view controller like that if you want to send messages before dismiss:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.parentViewController doSomething];
}
```

Comment: `modalViewNavController.parentViewController = self;` says error Assignment to readonly property

Comment: ViewDidDisappear can be called without your view being dismissed (for example, a camera is activated which hides your view but restores it after photo is taken).